# How can we solve this differential equation $d^nf(x)/dx^n=a$?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential

The differential equation
$$\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}=a.$$
My attempt I firstly solved the simpler version of it like
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=a,$$$$\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}=a,\ldots .$$
And got a generalistaion as
$$ f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c_i x^i}{i!}$$
as $i$ goes from $0$ to $n$ where $c_i$ is constant (including a) but how can we generalize this with rigorous proof please help me I needed the solution if this differential equation to prove that in circular motion we can neglect the $n$th derivative of displacement as if we limit this result (if I am right) to infinity then it tends to zero.

Comment: You can prove it generally using [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Comment: You have a hypothesis about what the solution looks like for a given $n$. Now you only have to prove it, and that is probably best done using mathematical induction, i.e. showing it for a base case (e.g. $n=0$) and then showing that if it's true for $n=k$ then it is also true for $n=k+1.$

Comment: MathJax works in the title section too, don't you know?

Comment: Thank you md2perpe i prooved using induction Should i close my question or write the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution is
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{ c_k x^k}{k!} + a \frac{x^n}{n!} $$
and differentiating this expression $n$ times show that indeed
$$ \frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n} = a $$
so it is a solution of the differential expression. You can use induction to compute the general derivative of a monomial $$\frac{d^n x^k}{dx^n}$$ and then use it in your proof.

Comment: Thank you triceratops i should have included in question that a is included in ci